# COPY command can't find the path specified when run in C#

Tags: c#, command-line, process, command

When I run he following command from the command line it works fine.

```
COPY "C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Application.evtx" "C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\Support\Logs\Application.evtx"
```

But I want to run it using the following in C#

```
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + CurrentCommand);
 StreamReader.procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

 // Do not create the black window.
 procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
 proc.Start();

 while (!proc.StandardError.EndOfStream)
 {
      sError = proc.StandardError.ReadLine();
      //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + sError);
 }

 proc.WaitForExit();
 // Get the output into a string
 sResult = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

`sResult` returns the following error:

> The system cannot find the path specified

Why is this?

Comment: Why are you doing it this complicated?? `File.Copy(oldFile, newFile)` from the `System.IO` namespace, and you're done!

Comment: Because there is a whole list of commands that are read in from an ini file and they all need to be run.  So I don't know what the commands are initially they are just passed in.

Comment: Could you stick those commands into a `mycommand.cmd` file and then just run that by calling `cmd /c mycommand.cmd` ??

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to "escape" the command parameters for the `cmd /c` argument like

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", string.Format("/c \"{0}\"", CurrentCommand));
```